# DevExpress Winforms XtraGrid ungroup column keeping original column order

Tags: winforms, devexpress, xtragrid

When ungrouping a column by dragging it back into the grid header panel, the column is inserted at the point where it is dragged. Is there a way to restore that column back at the original position it was before grouping?

Answer (score 0):

For end users? You can use the context menu to undo the grouping.

Unfortunately, mine is in german.

[image: DX Grouping]